A schema with 10 Fact Tables and 1 Dimension Table
Is it normal / best practice to have multiple fact tables but only minimal dimension table(s).
I am new to data modelling and trying to create the best / most efficient data model and it always seems as if I have way to many fact tables.
For context right now I am trying to measures multiple areas of my supply base and have these individual extracts to support this;
Invoices (total paid to supplier)
Demand (Supplier future needs)
Delivery Performance (Supplier on time deliveries)
Ethics (Supplier Ethical incidents)
Cyber (Supplier cyber attacks)
..........
and about 5 others.
The only fact table I have is of my supplier base.. thus becoming my only Dimension table...
is this normal? should I be looking to extract this data differently?
Building the above all joining to the dimension table..

If the data is structured that way, and you need all fact tables for reporting purposes, it is possible to have such model. Of course, fact tables should not be linked to one another, but each one can have a relationship with the dimension. Anyway, there is probably a problem with data quality. Or the business is trying to do a single report, that can be broken down in 5 reports. What is the total paid to supplier have to do with supplier cyber-attacks? In my opinion date dimension is always needed.

Hi, thanks for replying. Well each fact table is an extract from different system. The business is trying to get a full view of the supplier. So it is interested in how much has been paid to the supplier as well as how many cyber attacks that supplier has reported. I could add a date dimension too

how your data is structured in your source system(s) is irrelevant to how you design your dimensional model

Define your measures
Define the grain for each measure
Where measures have the same grain they can, but don’t have to, go in the same fact table
For each measure, define how you want to be able to filter and aggregate them. This gives you your dimensions

